# Facebook SDK : sometimes email field return null ( with "email" permission set )

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook App written in PHP. Asked for user's "email" permission. I noticed that I obtained **90%** of user's email address, but not some.

I know that the email permission allows Facebook App to get the primary email address stated in user's profile, but why does the SDK sometimes return `null`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"email" is an extended permission that users are not required to give when allowing an application.  If you need your users to grant the "email" permission before continuing in your app, you need to check that that permission is present before allowing the user to continue his workflow after authentication.

the graph API endpoint you need to use is `"/me/permissions"`

Here is a method that I use to do just that:

`permissions` is an array of strings that represent the permissions requested.

```
hasPermissions(["email"], function(hasPerms){
     alert(hasPerms);
 });

function hasPermissions(permissions, callback){
    console.log("perms requested");
    console.log(permissions);
    FB.api("/me/permissions", function(response){
        var hasPerms = true;
        console.log("perms obtaind");
        console.log(response);
        for(var i in permissions){
            console.log([permissions[i]] + " - " + response["data"][0][permissions[i]])
            hasPerms = hasPerms && response["data"][0][permissions[i]] == 1;
        }
        if(typeof callback == "function"){
            callback(hasPerms);     
        }       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think email is part of extended permission set. I asked for the email permission in the authorization dialog, it does not appear in the auth dialog.

Comment: incorrect. according to Facebook SDK , email is a part of extended permission set.

Comment: Could either of you please send a reference?